# Alias in Spark data frame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to define alias in case of multiple columns in a sub query. From example below I would like to define alias for avg(high) in the output of d

eg:

```
val d = c.select("date","high").groupBy("date").avg("high")
```

Comment: You can do it this way: `val d = c.select("date","high").groupBy("date").agg(avg("high").alias("avg_high"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `withColumnRenamed` for this:

```
val d = c
   .select("date","high")
   .groupBy("date")
   .avg("high")
   .withColumnRenamed("avg(high)", "Average High")
```